# Detect if presence of a character in a string with Lua

Tags: linux, nginx, lua

I can have two types of string: `nxs_flo_dev.nexus` or`fpdesk`.
I want to test if there is a `.` in the string.
If there is a `.` I divide the string otherwise I do not do anything.

```
if(ngx.var.host.contains('.') then 
    content_by_lua 'ngx.say(ngx.var.host:match("(.-)%."))';
end
```

Is there a function to do that? Because `.contains()` doesn't work.

Comment: Please make your question simpler and not a long list of failed attempts (unless they are instructive in some way). And, if your solution is a better answer than the existing ones, post it as an answer and accept it. But, the answer shouldn't be in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `match` again. Remember to escape the dot with `%.`:

```
if ngx.var.host:match('%.') then
```

If you want to do this inside `content_by_lua` do

```
content_by_lua 'if ngx.var.host:match('%.') then ngx.say(ngx.var.host:match("(.-)%.")) end';
```

Given your edit, this is the simplest solution:

```
content_by_lua 'ngx.say(ngx.var.host:match("(.-)%.") or ngx.var.host)';
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I updated my post because I have some errors.

Comment: @user9099802, I thought you meant Lua code, not nginx code.

Comment: I think it's the condition in the `if` that it does not work